# I did a High Resolution Timing in C on Windows? could anyone guide me to call a specific function at 2ms?

Tags: c, timer, operating-system, performancecounter

```
    hr_time.h:
    ----------
    #include <windows.h>

    typedef struct {
        LARGE_INTEGER start;
        LARGE_INTEGER stop;
    } stopWatch;

    void startTimer( stopWatch *timer);
    void stopTimer( stopWatch *timer);
    double LIToSecs( LARGE_INTEGER * L);
    double getElapsedTime( stopWatch *timer);
    ------------------------------------------------------
    hr_time.c:
    ------------
    #include <windows.h>

    #ifndef hr_timer
    #include "hr_time.h"
    #define hr_timer
    #endif

    void startTimer( stopWatch *timer) {
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&timer->start);
    }

    void stopTimer( stopWatch *timer) {
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&timer->stop);
    }

    double LIToSecs( LARGE_INTEGER * L) {
        LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
        QueryPerformanceFrequency( &frequency );
        return ((double)L->QuadPart /(double)frequency.QuadPart);
    }

    double getElapsedTime( stopWatch *timer) {
        LARGE_INTEGER time;
        time.QuadPart = timer->stop.QuadPart - timer->start.QuadPart;
        return LIToSecs( &time) ;
    }
#include "TIMER1.h"    
void main()
{
/**
 * how to make This task is activated every 2ms ??
 */
TASK( Task2ms )
{

    stopWatch s;
    startTimer(&s);

    if( XCPEVENT_DAQ_OVERLOAD & Xcp_DoDaqForEvent_2msRstr() )
    {

    }

        if( XCPEVENT_MISSING_DTO & Xcp_DoStimForEvent_2msRstr() )
        {

        }


        stopTimer(&s);
        getElapsedTime(&s);

}
}
```

if we take two readings at TimeStart and then TimeEnd then the difference is the number of counts. Divide this by the frequency of the counter- a value expressed as ticks per second and the result is the length of time that the timed code took to execute.

The above code is working fine but need some suggestions to call the function at 2ms or 10ms. could anyone help me in this ??

Declare a variable of type stopWatch eg s. Then before the code you wish to time, insert a startTimer( &s) function call and after the code, a stopTimer(&s) call. You can then call getElapsedTime(&s) to return the time in seconds accurate to microseconds.

Myquestion : How to call a specific function at 2ms or 10ms ?? Where to modify in the above code ??

I modified the code and added main function: Is it possible call the function (like:  XCPEVENT_DAQ_OVERLOAD & Xcp_DoDaqForEvent_2msRstr() and XCPEVENT_MISSING_DTO & Xcp_DoStimForEvent_2msRstr()) for every 2ms ??

Comment: You may also look at [Waitable Timer Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687008%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This appraoch requires less implemenattion effort than timer queues.

Answer (score 1):

The code excerpts in your question show how to measure elapsed time to high resolution. They do not show how to schedule periodic execution. That would require a timer.

As you no doubt know, the standard Win32 timer is a low resolution timer. You need a high resolution timer. The most commonly used example of which is a [multimedia timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743609.aspx). More recently these have been deprecated in favour of [timer queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686796.aspx).

Comment: should I use the below link as a code ??       http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: David Heffernan: I created a timer queue and also set the timer for 2ms and created a simple task to print hello. It's displaying only once as hello. How to make it to call the function for every 2ms ??